# Can my lcd monitor be fixed?

Tags: display

I have Samsung monitor manufactured in 2006. Model: 740n [R] D. It won't show image.

When computer is asleep the light on the power button of the monitor pulsates normally. But when the computer is start up, besides displaying nothing, no image, the power-button light adds in between its usual blinks, a weaker (lower light) blink.

Also, when I first encountered this problem, I would be sitting at my desk doing something else, with my computer running, and out of nowhere the image would just show up. And then again when I would turn off the computer and started it again tomorrow, display wouldn't work. Would you say its dead or maybe just something came loose?

Edit:
Its not the computer, and it is not the cables, I've done tests.

Comment: It sounds like there is some part that has gone bad, or maybe some kind of short. More than likely is possible to fix it, but depending on what is wrong with it, it would be more cost effective to get a new monitor.

Comment: I will open it up tomorrow then and look up for some obvious problems. Good to know there is hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bought a new 19", 4:3 monitor for 30$ after I disassmbled the old one, and couldn't figure out what's the problem.

*Just to not leave it unanswered.